# Unity: Reading image pixel color and instantiating object based on that

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to read image pixel colors, the image will be only Black and white. Therefore if the pixel is white i want to instantiate white cube and if pixel is black i want to instantiate black cube. Now This is all new to me so i made some digging and i ended up using system.Drawing and bitmaps. However now im stuck. I can't know how to check for the white pixel

For example

```
private void Pixelreader()
{
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(("ImageName.png");
    for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);

            if (pixel == *if image is white)
            {
               // instantiate white color.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there any other way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Better if u provided some visual stuff to explain better !

Comment: What visuals? Im just working with empty scene and image. The image will not be in the scene, i just need to load image and read it's pixels. The image will always be black or white. so if the pixel is black i want to debug black else debug white. then based on that i will do what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is truly black and white only (that is, all pixels are either equal to `System.Drawing.Color.Black` or `System.Drawing.Color.White`), then you could compare to these colors directly. Within the code you posted, it will look like this:

```
if (pixel == System.Drawing.Color.White)
{
    //instantiate white color.
}
```

If the image is part of your Unity assets, a better approach is to read it using Resources. Place the image into Assets/Resources folder; then you can use the following code:

```
Texture2D image = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("ImageName.png");
```

If the image is entirely black or entirely white, no need to loop - just check one pixel:

```
if(image.GetPixel(0,0) == Color.White)
{
    //Instantiate white cube
}
else
{
    //Instantiate black cube
}
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this but i keep getting errors. it says : ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]

Comment: This is how im loading my image :   Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Earth.png");

Comment: @Nanopili, can you verify that your bitmap is found and is loading properly? Keep in mind, the code you posted is trying to load the image from disk (not from assets within your Unity project)

Comment: Im also getting null for the image so the path must be wrong... : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Let me test this, but now you removed all the system.Drawing and bitmaps you are using only Unity ye? And nop the image will always be Black and white.

Comment: it's still giving me : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object  for the image

Comment: I changed the Texture2D into a public variable and i dragged in my image in the inspector. I clicked play and unity froze.. xD is it better if i make it public or load it from file which approch is better?

Comment: @Nanopili, ...why are you setting the image through the inspector? If you're doing that, you don't need to load it from resources, it's already loaded... Unity approach is better, since you're using Unity.

Comment: I commented the line from loading from source. But i want to load from resource, i made the inspector thing just to check if it's working. I actually prefer loading it rather than making it public but it's not working it's returning null

Comment: I added into the Resources folder and made sure the naming is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can actually load an image as a resource into a Texture2D, then use `UnityEngine.Texture2D` and `UnityEngine.Color.GrayScale` to check if the color you get out is sufficiently close to white.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are going a bit overboard with it and instead could use features already built in to Unity. Try taking a look in to getting the pixel color during a ray cast.

> ```
> if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit)) {
>      var TextureMap: Texture2D = hit.transform.renderer.material.mainTexture;
>      var pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
>          pixelUV.x *= TextureMap.width;
>          pixelUV.y *= TextureMap.height;
>
>          print ( "x=" + pixelUV.x + ",y=" + pixelUV.y + " " + TextureMap.GetPixel (pixelUV.x,pixelUV.y) );
> ```

[Taken from here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/163662/get-pixel-colour-on-a-ray-hit.html)

Comment: I don't really get it? how this is going to work? The ray cast will be casted from my camera towards the image? But i won't have the image on the scene i just want to read it and get it pixels..

Comment: Then I guess I am missing the whole point in this exercise? Where is the image and why are you reading from it?

Comment: The Image is in the Unity assets folder, i just need to access it and read it. the image will always be only black and white, so on white pixels i want white cube and on black pixels i want black cube that's it..